# How to generate Rank

Tags: php

I try to generate rank from database, but 0(zero) value show Rank - 1 always.

My Code

```
<?php $ra ="
 SELECT SUM(TermOneWritten),  FIND_IN_SET( TermOneWritten, (    
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT TermOneWritten
 ORDER BY TermOneWritten DESC) 
 FROM std_result WHERE StudentID =  '".$studentID."' GROUP BY StudentID)
 ) AS rank
 FROM std_result
 WHERE StudentID =  '".$studentID."' GROUP BY StudentID";
 $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $ra);
 while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
   echo "RANK -  " . $r["rank"]. "";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Not a solution, but improvement.use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: not work, But please tell how to create ranking system